# Use Regex to lookahead and redirect in case of match IIS

Tags: regex, iis

I have the following IIS rule which is supposed to redirect if the URI does not contain the word `Api`:

```
         <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^((?!Api).)*$" negate="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
```

This was working fine until I added a token as a query parameter for a route. Now when it tries to match that URI it will go out of memory.

How would I have to write the pattern so it looks only in the first 30 characters? The `/Api/` route will never appear later. This way I will make sure that the regular expression matching does not run out of memory when a token is present.

Comment: `pattern="^(?!.{0,27}Api).*"`?

Comment: Thank you. I just couldn't write the right pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure `Api` does not occur within the first 30 chars you may use

```
pattern="^(?!.{0,27}Api).*"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.{0,27}Api)` - a negative looakahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with any 0 to 27 chars (other than linebreak chars) and `Api` after them
- `.*` - any 0+ chars (other than linebreak chars).